# Converting a dataframe into a config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, config

```
def load_config_report(config_file_path):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    pharmacy_settings = pd.read_excel(config_file_path,
                                      sheet_name='pharmacy_settings')
    for each in pharmacy_settings['facility_name']:
        config[each]['facility_alias'] = pharmacy_settings['facility_alias']
        config[each]['facility_group_id'] = pharmacy_settings['facility_group_id']
        config[each]['invoice_num'] = pharmacy_settings['invoice_num']

    with open('X:\\Reports\\Invoices\\config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

Trying to convert the contents of an excel file into a .ini file. First column is the [section], remaining columns are variables in that section. Currently getting a KeyError due to how I'm iterating/slicing the dataframe. Is this a good approach to achieve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "X:\Python Dev\REFACTOR\invoicerefactor.py", line 41, in read_config
    options.load_config_report(config_file_path.get())
  File "X:\Python Dev\REFACTOR\options.py", line 10, in load_config_report
    config[each]['facility_alias'] = pharmacy_settings['facility_alias']
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'ALL CARE HEALTH SOLUTIONS'
```

Comment: What's the error message exactly?

Comment: Edit: Added error message. It's due to how I'm trying to index the configparser dictionary. https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Aside from initializing `config[each]`, I doubt you can just assign a series like `pharmacy_settings['facility_alias']` into a config key.

Comment: It would help to have some copy-pasted sample rows from `pharmacy_settings`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize an empty dictionary for `config[each]` before completing the data.

```
for each in pharmacy_settings['facility_name']:
    config[each] = {}
    config[each]['facility_alias'] = pharmacy_settings['facility_alias']
    #...
```

That's how the examples in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) are doing it.

Comment: This was part of the problem, but it's also because of how I'm trying to set the variables with [each] and set them equal to a series like pharmacy_settings.